# What SQL will allow me to find all unique tokens from a textfield in my database?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have table with two key fields:

1. title (varchar)
2. category_id (int)

I want to be able to get a distinct list of all tokens / words that form strings in the title field and count their occurrences in the whole table.

After an hour of research I have to admit I'm stumped on this one, hoping the community can offer some advice.

Comment: allowed to write a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality in MySQL to accomplish this.  You'll need to write a function to split a varchar into tokens, or use an [existing solution](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/).  In a script or stored procedure, you should be able to combine the split function with a `LIKE` query to determine how many times each token occurs.